# Extension Method on IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

What is the solution for writing extension method dor IEumerable which resurns for example sum of squarea of elemetns

for example for:

```
IList<double> L = new List<double>();
L.Add(1);
L.Add(2);
L.Add(3);

var result = L.MyMethod();
```

expected value of result is 1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 = 14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an extension method. You can just say

```
var sumOfSquares = list.Sum(x => x * x);
```

Obviously you can make it an extension method with

```
public static class EnumerableDoubleExtensions {
    public static double SumSquares(this IEnumerable<double> source) {
        Contract.Requires(source != null);
        return source.Sum(x => x * x);
     }
}
```

To do product you just say

```
list.Aggregate(1d, (p, x) => p * x);
```

which you can easily make an extension method via

```
public static class EnumerableDoubleExtensions {
    public static double Product(this IEnumerable<double> source) {
        Contract.Requires(source != null);
        return source.Aggregate(1d, (p, x) => p * x);
     }
}
```

Note that this uses [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx) of which `Enumerable.Sum` is a special case.

Comment: Ok but lets say I want to have as a result multiplicity 1 * 2 * 3 ? I just want to know the way of doing it :)

Comment: Regarding the product; it's not a good idea to use the overload that takes an initial seed since the method will return `1` for an empty sequence.

Comment: Could You please show me how to make an extension method from this ?

Comment: @Ani: The result of an empty product is one. This is a mathematical fact (or definition depending on your perspective). So, it is a good idea since it produces the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use the overload of [**`Enumerable.Sum`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734.aspx) that sums up a sequence of *projected* values from a sequence:

```
public static double GetSumOfSquares(this IEnumerable<double> numbers)
{
    if(numbers == null)
       throw new ArgumentNullException("numbers");

    return numbers.Sum(x => x * x);
}
```

Do note that this will return `0D` for an empty sequence. This is similar to:

```
numbers.Select(x => x * x)
       .Sum();
```

---

As for your question about multiplying them, you could use [**`Enumerable.Aggregate`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx), which is a more general operator for performing accumulation-operations on sequences:

```
double product = numbers.Aggregate((productSoFar, next) => productSoFar * next);
```

This will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if the sequence is empty. If you would like to return something else in this case, use the overload that accepts an initial seed.

Comment: ok so how about writing mehtod which will return multiplicity ? 1 * 2 * 3  ?

Comment: OK and now I would like to have opportunity to call MyList.MyCustomAggregation which will give the result You wrote? Could You please show me how to write such method as an extension to IEnumerable ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @gruber: You mean in general? Or specifically for the multiplication?

Comment: @Ani, maybe any good resources to read about extension methods? I dont know from where all of You take all this information, msdn gives only simple examples ...

Comment: @gruber: I would suggest picking up a good C# book. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795/recommended-books-for-learning-c Here's a short MSDN page about extension-methods:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx